# When dragover to specific column i want to prevent that inserting into that column in js

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable

When drag-over to specific column I want to prevent that inserting into that column. Inside of inserting I want show default ghost icon(disable) using javascript

```
     $(document).ready(function () {

                    $(function () {
                        var kanbanCol = $('.panel-body');
                        kanbanCol.css('max-height', (window.innerHeight - 150) + 'px');

                        var kanbanColCount = parseInt(kanbanCol.length);
                        $('.scrumview').css('min-width', (kanbanColCount * 350) + 'px');

                        draggableInit();

                    });

                    function draggableInit() {
                        var sourceId;

                        $('[draggable=true]').bind('dragstart', function (event) {
                            sourceId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
                            // alert("SourceID  "+sourceId)
                            event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", event.target.getAttribute('id'));
                        });


     $('.panel-body').bind('dragover', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });


       $('.panel-body').bind('drop', function (event) {
                            alert();
                            var children = $(this).children();
                            var targetId = children.attr('id');
                            // alert("TargetID  " + targetId)

                            if (sourceId != targetId && (sourceId == 'Processingforreq') && targetId =='QCtest') {
                                var elementId = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
                                $('#processing-modal').modal('show');
                                $('#confirmUpdate').on('click', function () {
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
                                        children.prepend(element);
                                        // $('#processing-modal').modal('toggle');
                                    }, 1000);
                                });
                            }
                            else if (sourceId != targetId && (sourceId == 'QCtest') && targetId =='Filling') {
                                var elementId = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
                                $('#processing-modal').modal('show');
                                $('#confirmUpdate').on('click', function () {
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
                                        children.prepend(element);
                                    }, 1000);
                                });
                            }
});
```

[image]

> refer site:-https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/0yDZy

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible to remove that. I think it might depend on the browser you use. Though if you find an answer I'd love to know as I've been working on a to do list like yours and I also have that 'ghost icon' there

Comment: @TomTruyen It can possible.If I get the solution definitelyI will  post it. thank you

Comment: I have found this CSS library that has made it so that it works. Maybe if you look into their code you find your solution https://getuikit.com/docs/sortable

Comment: @TomTruyen not working..